# Leaflet filtering data with dropdown menu

Tags: leaflet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WamR6.jpg)I'm doing a project where I want to show boat trips. The data is in a geojson file and I intend to filter the information through a dropdown menu.

See the example:

```js
// Map your choices to your option value
var lookup = {
    'John1':['selecione 1 ano','1601','1602','1603'],
    'Dre1': ['selecione 1 ano','1604','1605'],
    
};


// When an option is changed, search the above for matching choices
$('#escolhaNavegador').on('change', function() {
   // Set selected option as variable
   var selectValue = $(this).val();

// Empty the target field
   $('#escolhaAno').empty();

 // For each choice in the selected option
   for (i = 0; i < lookup[selectValue].length; i++) {
      // Output choice in the target field
      $('#escolhaAno').append("<option value='" + lookup[selectValue][i] + "'>" + lookup[selectValue][i] + "</option>");
   }
});

EDIT:
Here is my javascript code for building the map:


//Leaflet code

var map = L.map ('MapDiv',{
    center: [48.34654412118006, -2.29326171875],
    zoom: 5,
    zoomControl: false,
    minZoom:5,
    dragging: true
});



var OpenStreetMap_Mapnik = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 19,
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
}).addTo(map);




var PortoLisboa = L.circleMarker ([38.72194763292809,-9.12689208984375]).addTo(map)
var PortoValencia = L.marker ([39.44918459383021,-0.32684326171875]).addTo(map)
var PortoBarcelona = L.marker ([41.36134940442383,2.164306640625]).addTo(map)
var PortoLivorno = L.marker ([43.547490543573396,10.301485061645508]).addTo(map)
//Depois de criados os dois vetores vamos agrupa-los numa variavel overlay
var overlay = {
  "Porto de Lisboa": PortoLisboa,
  "Porto de Valência": PortoValencia,
  "Porto de Barcelona":PortoBarcelona,
  "Porto de Livorno":PortoLivorno

   };


L.control.layers ({},overlay,{
            collapsed: true,
 }).addTo(map);

L.geoJSON(exemplo1).addTo(map);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id='escolhaNavegador' name='escolhaNavegador'>

                    <option id='EscNav' name='John' value=''>Escolha um navegador</option>
                    <option id='EscNavJohn' name='John' value='John1'>John</option>
                    <option id='EscNavDre' name='Dre' value='Dre1'>Dre</option>

                </select>

                <select id='escolhaAno' name='escAno'>

                    <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione um ano</option>

                </select>
```

Briefly:

After selecting the name and year I want it to be added to the boat trip line.

Can anyone help?

thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is the "_boat trip line_"? Where is the code where you use Leaflet?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just added the code for building the map.

Comment: So how do you associate your selected options value with your GeoJSON data? Adding a sample would very probably help.

Comment: I wish it were like this map (http://ahalota.github.io/Leaflet.CountrySelect/demo.html). Clicking on an option would add a line for the year or captain.